# Connected App / OAuth Scopes - Access the Salesforce API Platform (sfap_api)

Tags: connected-apps, oauth

Does anyone have any idea what this OAuth Scope is?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_tokens_scopes.htm&type=5), it's reserved for future use.

Note to future visitors: please comment if this answer is outdated.